# Pycharm Pytest parallel testing error 'E fixture 'driver' not found' can anyone help on how to fix this?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, driver, fixtures

def test_login(driver):
E       fixture 'driver' not found

> ```
>   available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatc
> ```

h, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, testrun_uid, tmp_path,
tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory, worker_id

> ```
>   use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
> ```

I have the pytest fixture setup for driver but I'm not sure how to approach this?

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67159968/edit) your answer to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

Although I do feel a bit stupid for this, it might help someone else so what I'd done was to name the 'conftest.py' file as 'comftest.py' with an incorrect 'm' instead or the correct 'n'!
Now my 'pytest -n 2' command is working from the terminal in Pycharm.